# Unable to redirect the output of the system command to a file named error.log and stderr to another file named test_file.errorlog

Tags: perl

This perl script is traversing all directories and sub directories, searching for a file named `RUN` in it. Then it opens the file and runs the 1st line written in the file. The problem is that I am not able to redirect the output of the system command to a file named `error.log` and `STDERR` to another file named `test_file.errorlog`, but no such file is created.

Note that all variable are declared if not found.

```
find (\&pickup_run,$path_to_search);

### Subroutine for extracting path of directories with RUN FILE PRESENT
sub pickup_run {
    if ($File::Find::name =~/RUN/) {
        ### If RUN file is present , push it into array named run_file_present
        push(@run_file_present,$File::Find::name);
    }
}

###### Iterate over the array containing paths to directories containing RUN files one by one 
foreach my $var (@run_file_present) {
    $var =~ s/\//\\/g;
    ($path_minus_run=$var) =~ s/RUN\b//;
    #print "$path_minus_run\n";

    my $test_case_name;
    ($test_case_name=$path_minus_run) =~ s/expression to be replced//g;

    chdir "$path_minus_run";
    ########While iterating over the paths, open each file
    open data, "$var";

    #####Run the first two lines containing commands 
    my @lines = <data>;

    my $return_code=system (" $lines[0] >error.log 2>test_file.errorlog");
    if($return_code) {
        print "$test_case_name \t \t FAIL \n";
    }
    else {
        print "$test_case_name \t \t PASS \n";
    }
    close (data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that `$lines[0]` has a newline at the end after being read from the file

But there are several improvements you could make

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program, and declare all your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use
- Use the *three-parameter form of `open`* and always check whether it succeeded, putting the built-in variable `$!` into your `die` string to say *why* it failed. You can also `use autodie` to save writing the code for this manually for every open, but it requires Perl v5.10.1 or better
- You shouldn't put quotes around scalar variables -- just used them as they are. so `chdir $path_minus_run` and `open data, $var` are correct

There is also no need to save all the files to be processed and deal with them later. Within the `wanted` subroutine, `File::Find` sets you up with `$File::Find::dir` set to the directory containing the file, and `$_` set to the bare file name without a path. It also does a `chdir` to the directory for you, so the context is ideal for processing the file

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

my $path_to_search;

find( \&pickup_run, $path_to_search );

sub pickup_run {

    return unless -f and $_ eq 'RUN';

    my $cmd = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $_;
        <$fh>;
    };
    chomp $cmd;

    ( my $test_name = $File::Find::dir ) =~ s/expression to be replaced//g;

    my $retcode = system( "$cmd >error.log 2>test_file.errorlog" );

    printf "%s\t\t%s\n", $test_name, $retcode ? 'FAIL' : 'PASS';
}
```

Comment: Yeah the problem was indeed related to chomp. I chomped the lines[0] and redirected it and voila! it worked. Thanks for the insight and suggestions. I am new to perl and have been using it since 15 days. So i will learn along the way !